# Alternative for REGEXP_INSTR command output in Amazon RedShift

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift

As you all are aware [REGEXP_INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions129.htm) command in *Oracle/PLSQL* allows you to search a string for a regular expression pattern. It also provides three parameters namely **start_position**, **nth_appearance**, **return_option**.

Redshift also supports the [same command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_INSTR.html) but doesn't  support all the three parameters due to which the following query totally functioning in Oracle/PLSQL wouldn't function in Redshift.

***substr(some_string, REGEXP_INSTR(some_string, '/regex1/', 1,1,1), 15));***
(redshift uses substring instead of substr)

In the query above REGEXP_INSTR returns the  position of the character after the occurrence of the pattern as we have set the return_option to 1.
(i.e if a match ends at position 3 it will return 4. Thus from position 4 , 15 characters  will be extracted from "some_string")

We can't set the return option to 1 in Redshift as the REGEXP_INSTR command doesn't support parameters. I'm looking for alternative ways to return the next position value of where the match occurs.

Comment: Your description isn't quite right. Unless `/regex1/` matches a single character the return will be higher than 4 - it's the position after the end of the matches section, not that the position immediately after the start of the match; and it will get the 15 characters from that position, i.e. 4 to 18 not 4 to 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you could do:

```
substr(some_string, regexp_instr(some_string, '/regex1/', 1, 1, 0)
  + length(regexp_substr(some_string, '/regex1/', 1, 1)), 15)
```

The `regexp_substr()` gives you the part of the string that matched the same pattern as the `regexp_instr()` call; adding the length of that matched section to the `instr` location offsets the result by that much. Which has the same effect as setting return-opt to 1, at least in this scenario.

Not familiar with RedShift, but from the docs it looks like the same sort of thing should work:

```
substring(some_string, regexp_instr(some_string, '/regex1/', 1)
  + len(regexp_substr(some_string, '/regex1/', 1)), 15)
```

The position argument can be skipped in both versions as you're using the default value of 1, as can nth-occurrence argument in Oracle (now return-opt is the default zero too); but this will still not work if you don't want the first occurrence. You'd need to modify the pattern to try to pick up a later occurrence. Hopefully that isn't an issue though.

You'll also need to check that happens (in both systems) if there is no match, or other edge cases.

Comment: First Occurrence is  what I was looking for. Thanks :)